# Disabling wlan0 adapter

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, mac-address

**Question:**

What is the terminal command behind right clicking on the wireless icon (Ubuntu 15.04) and then unchecking "Enable Wi-Fi" the box?

**Why am I asking it?**

`macchanger` just work for me when I disable my wifi via GUI, call `sudo macchanger -e wlan0` and enable the wifi via GUI again.

When I try using the command lines below, although I get no error, at the end my MAC address remains the same:

- `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`
- `sudo macchanger -e wlan0`
- `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`

Same applies when I try with:

- `sudo ip link set dev wlan0 down`
- ...

Comment: Would [one of my previous answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213801/internet-connectivity-issues-due-to-wrong-mac-address-using-linux-mint-17-2) be a more appropriate solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using NetworkManager (and you very likely are): `nmcli radio wifi off`. This is simply a command line interface equivalent of the widget. NetworkManager is a complicated beast. I'm not sure what the basic commands are that it's using.

Comment: works perfectly. very appreciated